# How do i write an expression for exclusion of IP range in Google Analytics?

Tags: ip, expression, internal

What is the correct expression or code to exclude a range of IP addresses in google analytics? range is:  192.168.1.10-192.168.1.254

Answer (score 0):

Must be in a regular expression.  See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en

^192.168.1.([1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-4]))$

try the following link to create other ip address ranges 
http://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex